# Package not downloading

Tags: r, macos, rattle

I keep getting this error message when trying to run a Paired two sample correlation test in R. Message:

> Error: package ‘timeDate’ required by ‘fBasics’ could not be found

I am on Mac and this happens when I try to download the fBasics package to run the test.

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("timeDate")`

Comment: Just did and it downloaded but didnt solve the problem. Now the error message pops up saying Error: package ‘timeSeries’ required by ‘fBasics’ could not be found. I then proceeded to install that package and got this error message

Comment: Same thing.  You have to get all the needed packages.

Comment: Just got this error messageError in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/timeSeries_3042.102.tgz'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/timeSeries_3042.102.tgz': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘timeSeries’ failed

Comment: Try `install.packages("fBasics", dependencies = TRUE)`. And try a different CRAN mirror if one has issues. RStudio makes this easier.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute in your r console:

```
install.packages("timeDate", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
install.packages("fBasics", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

For ubuntu users, you can install with apt `r-cran-fbasics` and `r-cran-timedate` packages.